# Why HashMap<K,V> in Java iterates in order?

Tags: java, hashmap

`HashMap` always returns values ordered by keys although documentation says it's not guaranteed:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(8, "B");
    map.put(7, "C");
    map.put(5, "A");
    map.put(10, "Z");
    map.put(3, "D");
    map.put(1, "B");
    System.out.println(map);
    printCollection(map);
}

private static void printCollection(Map<Integer, String> map) {
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> pair : map.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " " + pair.getValue());
    }
}
```

Output:
{1=B, 3=D, 5=A, 7=C, 8=B, 10=Z}

```
1 B
3 D
5 A
7 C
8 B
10 Z
```

Comment: Try changing the declaration to `new HashMap<>(4)`. That will give you a different order.

Comment: @user1274184 check the answer below. I have put an example. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

"Not guaranteed" doesn't mean "never". Probably you just had luck, and you should not rely on that.

If you want an ordered HashMap you should use `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: It's not luck, there is a definitive explanation why he is getting this result (it is not random in this case)

Comment: It is luck by definition: he's getting an ordered list while that property is not guaranteed. Obviously the inner-workings of the map are not "magic", there is a specific implementation (i know that), but from his point of view should be irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

You are testing with a very small set of key. The default size of the HashMap is 16, so it is storing them in order and sending back.

> Constructs an empty HashMap with the default initial capacity (16) and the default load factor (0.75).

The `hashcode` for `Integer` is value itself, so they will be stored in the each of the bucket.

Try this simple code and see the output:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i<100; i++) {
  map.put(i, "a");
}
for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet())
   System.out.print(entry.getKey() + "  ");
```

**Output:**
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 17 16 19 18 21 20 23 22 25 24 27 26 29 28 31 30 34 35 32 33 38 39 36 37 42 43 40 41 46 47 44 45 51 50 49 48 55 54 53 52 59 58 57 56 63 62 61 60 68 69 70 71 64 65 66 67 76 77 78 79 72 73 74 75 85 84 87 86 81 80 83 82 93 92 95 94 89 88 91 90 98 99 96 97

Till 15 keys are sorted, but then they start spreading randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are getting in this case. But not  guaranteed as doc said. Order will change if you keep adding and removing overtime.

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.